# Android Menu Options Action

Tags: android, android-menu

I understand how to create menu in Android. But what about the actions that they perform for each menu item? Do i have to specify them in each activity? or is there a "Android" way of doing this? I mean we can create a class and just refer to that class as it is Java but was thinking about "Android" way of doing it.

To be more clear, I create a menu in res/menu folder lets say standard_menu.xml and everything is looking good, but there is no accompanying java class file.

EDIT:
Ok I think i was not more clear. What I am trying to say is. Should I specify these actions for each menu item in EACH and EVERY activity that i use this menu?

Comment: You should override, `onOptionsItemSelected` method of each activity or fragment which you have initiated with a menu. Depending on `itemid`, you will do your work. Each click on a menu item is directed to this method.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I am saying... shld I do it for EACH and EVERY activity? or is there an ANDROID way?

Comment: For each activity that you have attached menu, yes

Comment: there is no android way but you can have a java way for that. check my answer. i tried to solve your problem, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try like these. Implement these methods in your activity

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.your menu item id) {
           //do some action
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: BUT this is what I have to specify for each and every activity right?

Answer (score 0):

following are the two functions that you have to override in your Activity :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

you will override these in each of your Activity .

Comment: BUT this is what I have to specify for each and every activity right?

Comment: Seems a bit redundant isn't it?

Comment: I am not sure but i think in Android Studio it copies these in any new Activity you create automatically  .

Answer (score 0):

every activity class have method `onCreateOptionsMenu`. if you want same menu for more then one activity simple write some `inflant()` method thats it & for override what you can do is call your own method from same class. thats it.

**for Activity1**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return MyClass.myMenuClick(item);
}
```

**for Activity2**

```
//same
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return MyClass.myMenuClick(item);
}

MyClass {...
    public static boolean myMenuClick(MenuItem item){
            int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.your menu item id) {
        //do some action
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

**NOTE**
My class can be anything. if you want to create external `public` class then also it wont make any problem. but its good practice if it can be an internal class.
or just make public static method in your `MainActivity`.

Comment: yes this is correct, but how does professional apps have it? I meant to learn how pros do it.

Comment: It is a best practice to have different menus for all activities but if your whole app contains same menus then you should go with inner class porfationals use all of three ideas(inner class, new class or static method only) but is is based on ur requirement